# Installation of tomcat7 for eclipse on Ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ubuntu

I want to install tomcat in order to use it on Eclipse, on Ubuntu, but, in the menu Window -> Preferences I dont see a menu Tomcat, and in Window -> Preferences -> Server -> Runtime environnement neither.

How to do it ?

I have tried to follow as proposes on the following links:
https://openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/environnement-tomcat-eclipse-sous-ubuntu-58429
https://askubuntu.com/questions/310767/how-should-i-install-apache-tomcat-7-for-use-with-eclipse

But it doesn't work at all.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to install the Java EE relaetd component in Eclipse to get the servers view and other Java web application related tools.

Comment: Yes, I have already installed java EE, But in runtimeenvironment I have only J2EE basics tools.

Comment: In Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environments there is a button `Add...` Clicking it allows you to download and install a server runtime environment. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes of course, but there is no Tomcat...